# Is it possible to override a method in a 3rd party library?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, methods, reflection

I am using the 3rd party library Google VR in Unity.
Within one C#-source file of that lib, I add a static method call to a class LibClass like this:

```
void onPrerender() {
    MyOwnClass.staticMethod();
    (continue with original method call...)
}
```

But every time I update the library, the call to MyOwnClass.staticMethod() is lost and I have to re-add it manually.
I can not subclass LibClass, because the library would always call LibClass and not LibSubClass. 
Is there a way to programmatically add the call to staticMethod() to LibClass? Or any other way?

Edit:
I've been asked to describe the problem better:

[OnPreRender](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnPreRender.html) is a method of the MonoBehaviour class of Unity.
This method is called before the image of the camera is rendered.
My problem is I need Google VR, which handles 2 separate cameras for each eye, to draw one of the camera images slightly different than the other.
Since OnPreRender is called for each of the cameras, I used this as an entry point for calling a static method in my own class (static only because that way I don't have to instantiate my own class in Google VRs class).

This works fine for many months now, but the Google VR lib is constantly updated and each time I do that, the method call to my own class is lost.

So I was wondering wether it is possible to kind of programmatically say "You there, OnPreRender() in that external class, when you are called by the library, jump over here and do some extra work."
Does that make sense?

Comment: It's not possible to override any `static` method anywhere. What you need to do is [explain your real goal here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) -- *why are you calling MyOwnClass.staticMethod() in onPrerender?* -- and we can help you solve the problem you are trying to solve by altering the library.

Comment: Dear Ed, I tried to explain my real goal. Is that better?

Comment: Thanks for the update. That does make sense. I'd tag this with [tag:Unity] if I were you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using extension methods. Bare in mind this work only for the static calls to object functions.

You can find more: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods

Comment: Thank you. It seems to me that this would be useful if I could call the method in question on my own. Unfortunately, it's called by the library. I think I did not explain well on my first try. Sorry for that. I edited the question and tried to explain better.